# Is there a General Implementation of the General Update Pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, data-synchronization

The d3.js Library uses the General Update Pattern to describe a mutation of a HTML/SVG Tree by a data array using functions separating the entering, updating and exiting elements. (See [d3-selection](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_join))

Is there any other implementation for the General Update Pattern describing an update for more general forms of state data like two arrays?

Something similar to this:

```js
const state = [{id:1, data:"foo", data2:"foo"}, {id:2, data:"bar"}]
const change = [{id:1, data:"baz"}, {id:3, data:"qux"}]

const nextState = select(state, entry => entry.id)
    .update(change, entry => entry.id)
    .join(
        enter => enter,
        update => update,
        exit => {}
    )
    .each(function (d) {Object.assign(this, d)})
    .value()

console.log(nextState)
// [{id:1, data:"baz", data2:"foo"}, {id:3, data: "qux"}]


// Implementation sketch:
function select(state, keyF) {
    const stateMap = new Map()
    state.forEach(entry => stateMap.set(keyF(entry), entry))
    let changeMap = new Map()

    const selection = {
        update(change, keyF) {
            change.forEach(entry => changeMap.set(keyF(entry), entry))
            return selection
        },
        join(enterF, updateF, exitF) {
            // ...
            return selection
        },
        each(callback) {
            stateMap.forEach((current, key) => callback.call(current, changeMap.get(key), key, state))
            return selection
        },
        value() {
            return stateMap.values()
        }
    }
    return selection
}
```